# AngularJS: User can register twice, how to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, jax-rs

The problem is, user can fill up the register form twice with the same username/email, and submit, before the app recognizes that there already exists a user with the given username and/or email. This bug might be something stupid, but I can't seem to find it for an hour already. Insight would be appreciated.

- Controller:

```js
app.controller('volonterController', function($scope, volonterFactory, teritorijaFactory) {
 
    function init() {
     console.log('volonterController.Init');
        volonterFactory.getVolonteri().success(function (data) {
         $scope.volonteri = data;
  });
        teritorijaFactory.getTeritorije().success(function (data2) {
         $scope.teritorije = data2;
  });
    }
 init();
 
 $scope.addVolonter = function(volonter) {
  volonterFactory.addVolonter(volonter).success(function(data) {
   toast('Volonter ' + volonter.username + " registered.");
  }); 
 };
 
 $scope.submit1 = function() {
  $scope.volonter.username;
  $scope.volonter.password;
  $scope.volonter.name;
  $scope.volonter.lastName;
  $scope.volonter.phone;
  $scope.volonter.email;
  $scope.volonter.teritorija;
  $scope.volonter.picturePath;
  $scope.volonter.state = "active";
  $scope.alreadyExists = false;
  
    
     for(var i=0; i < $scope.volonteri.length; i++) {
     if($scope.volonteri[i].username===$scope.volonter.username) {
      alert('Volonter with the given username already exists.');
      $scope.alreadyExists = true;
     }
     if($scope.volonteri[i].email===$scope.volonter.email) {
      alert('That email address is already in use.');
      $scope.alreadyExists = true;
     }
     }
     if($scope.alreadyExists===false) {
     $scope.addVolonter($scope.volonter);
     init();
     }
 }
});
```

- Service:

```js
app.factory('volonterFactory', function($http) {
 
 var factory = {};
 factory.getVolonteri = function() {
  return $http.get('/WP/rest/fileData/getVolonteri');
 };

 factory.addVolonter = function(volonter) {
  return $http.post('/WP/rest/fileData/addVolonter', volonter);
 };
 
 return factory;
 
});
```

- BackEnd java rest post method if it's needed:

  ```
  @POST
  @Path("/addVolonter")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String addVolonter(Volonter v) {
      getFileData().getVolonteri().put(v.getUsername(), v);
      System.out.println("Volonter " + v.getPassword()
          + " added.");
      return "OK";
  }
  ```

Comment: Volunteer is spelled Volunteer

Comment: It's spelled correctly. The original code was not in english, i just changed most of the variable names to make it easier for people to understand my question.

Comment: user is in control of the front-end, so you shouldn't even try to disable the button for submission with `ng-disable`, and just simply check everything in your backend, primarily you should check if user exists before you register him, to avoid the collision (otherwise you can register not just twice but as many times as you want). Maybe I'm missing something in your code that already does it

Comment: are you writing the username/ password data to a `file`? this could be the reason.
Say for example before the first request username / password was written back to file, the request came in to write same username / password. it would think that it does not exist and both are written back to the file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should at least be done server-side by your JAX-RS code but can be done client-side to improve the usability of your application.

When the user tries to register, your server-side code needs to 1st check if a user already has the supplied username and respond with an error code if one already exists, then catch that client-side in angular and show a message/warning/error. For example:

```js
// angular
$http.post('/WP/rest/fileData/addVolonter', volunteer).then(function () {
    $state.go(page.VOLUNTEER_DETAILS);
}).catch(function (response) {
    notify.error(response.msg);
});
```

```java
// Java (JAX-RS)
@POST
@Path("/volunteer")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addVolunteer(VolunteerDto volunteer) {
    if (volunteerService.usernameExists(volunteer.getUsername())) {
        Response.status(Status.CONFLICT).entity("{\"msg\":\"Duplicate username\"}").build();
        return;
    }

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Once you've done that, you can then improve the usability by checking the username as soon as it's been entered (or is changed):

```
<input type="text" ng-change="vm.usernameChanged()" ng-model="vm.username" />
```

```js
// angular
vm.usernameChanged = function() {
    $http.post('/WP/rest/fileData/checkUsername', vm.username).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.isValid);
    }).catch(function (response) {
        notify.warning(response.msg);
    });
};
```

```java
// Java (JAX-RS)
@POST
@Path("/checkUsername")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response checkUsername(String username) {
    boolean valid = volunteerService.usernameExists(username);
    return Response.ok().entity("{\"isValid\":" + valid + "}").build();
}
```

Comment: I'll try it your way, moving the check to the backend, thanks.

Comment: @newdev I updated the answer with an example of client-side validation